# ESTABLISHED tcp/ip port and what it means in a persistence connection

Tags: c#, tcp

[image]

- The above shows two netstat command I ran 8 hours apart.
- It shows that the same client IP connect to our port 11652.
- Our 11652 port is currently set to be persistence.

I'm not sure what it mean seeing two established connection from the same client IP but different port mean.

There are two possibilities I could think of, their port is either set to persistence or not persistence.

If their connection is not persistence, does this show that the client end might have dropped the connection at one point but we don't and that is why it shows 2 "ESTABLISHED" connection?

If their connection is persistence then why would I see two established sessions?

Comment: This isn't strictly a programming question, but it appears that your client has simply established a second connection. That is allowed by TCP/IP, though it could be a bug in the client that it did that. The fact that both connections show here as established means that both ends maintain both connections.

Comment: Could there be a second instance of the client running, perhaps on another desktop?

Comment: this is an interface connection on the back end so I doubt there is another instance, but it could be another "new" connection being made.  I'm trying to make sense of it too.